# compiling CGAL 4.3 on Windows 7

Tags: visual-c++, build-process, cgal

### I have

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Visual Studio 10 32 bit
- QT 4.84
- Boost 1.55
- CMake 2.8.8
- CGAL 4.3

### I did

Downloaded and built everyting before building  CGAL 4.3 itself. 
Run Cmake *as administrator* to avoid possible permissione issues.

### I get

[image]

"Impossible to start application correctly"

```
Microsoft (R) Visual Studio versione 10.0.40219.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. Tutti i diritti riservati.
1>------ Inizio compilazione: Progetto: cmTryCompileExec2140561810, Configurazione: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler versione 16.00.40219.01 per 80x86
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti riservati.
1>  
1>  cl /c /I"C:/CGAL-4.3/auxiliary/gmp/include" /Zi /W3 /WX- /Od /Ob0 /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D _DEBUG /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:strict /fp:except- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /GR /Fo"cmTryCompileExec2140561810.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"C:/CGAL-4.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTryCompileExec2140561810.pdb" /Gd /TP /wd4503 /analyze- /errorReport:prompt "C:\CGAL-4.3\config\support\print_GMP_version.cpp"  /Zm1000 /bigobj 
1>  
1>  print_GMP_version.cpp
1>C:\CGAL-4.3\auxiliary\gmp\include\gmp.h(2177): warning C4146: operatore 'meno' unario utilizzato con tipo unsigned. Il risultato resta unsigned.
1>  cmTryCompileExec2140561810.vcxproj -> C:\CGAL-4.3\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTryCompileExec2140561810.exe
========== Compilazione: 1 completate, 0 non riuscite, 0 aggiornate, 0 ignorate ==========

Exit code 0xc000007b
```

So this is a `GMP` problem. The same happens with `MPFR` compilaton and after this :

*any* `CGAL` test like

```
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NESTED_CLASS_FRIEND_DECLARATION_BUG - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_LIMITS - Failed
Performing Test CGAL_CFG_NO_NEXTAFTER - Failed
...
```

failed with the same `0xc000007b` error. Not sure if this related to previous errors or not.

### Question

Did anyone experienced the problem like this and if yes how did he suceed to compile CGAL ?

Comment: Drop /WX (or disable warning C4146 one way or another). VC gives a useless warning, and you are asking it to treat it as an error.

Comment: @MarcGlisse should not this comment be an answer? Without an answer a question cannot be closed.

Comment: @lrineau I hate the bureaucracy.

Answer (score 2):

Drop `/WX` (or disable warning C4146 one way or another). VC gives a useless warning, and you are asking it to treat it as an error.

Comment: but the command line says /WX-, so it's *no* WX. it's already disabled.

Comment: Ah... ok, sorry for misreading. Then, contrary to what you said, this has nothing to do with the GMP warning (you could try removing /W3 to be sure) and things are failing without providing any information. Maybe you'll have more luck with 2012... Actually, you could try to pass `--debug-trycompile` to cmake. Then you can try to run cmTryCompileExec.exe manually to see why it fails (missing DLL path?). I also don't think running as an admin should be necessary.